# `<p style="text-align:right">` is not working in a table

Tags: html

I have a table for invoices, when I want a curtain pricing to be aligned on the right.

So I have `<p style="text-align:right">$aos_products_price</p>`, but it is still moving it to the left. Is there anyway I can force it to the right?

Heres the HTML for the whole table:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Date:</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>$aos_invoices_date_entered</p>
            </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-top: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid
            black;">No:</td>

            <td style="border-top: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid
            black;">@</td>

            <td style="border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid;
             border-top-color: black; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-
             bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: black; text-align: 
             center;">Description</td>

            <td style="border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid;
             border-top-color: black; text-align: right; border-bottom: 1px
             solid black;">Balance</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>$aos_products_quotes_product_qty</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p style="text-align:right">$aos_products_price</p> <!--here-->
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
                <p style="text-align: center;">$aos_products_quotes_item_description</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>$aos_products_quotes_product_unit_price</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

By the way, its in a CRM with an html editor, converting the invoice to pdf. Can someone help me?

Comment: maybe you missing !important.

Comment: Working for me, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it!

Instead of:

```
<td>
  <p stlye="text-align: right">$aos_products_price</p>
</td>
```

I just used:

```
<td style="text-align:right">
  $aos_products_price
</td>
```

The editor that I am using seems to like `<p>` tags a lot